# Connection problems with H2 when starting from Java and usage of dbunit

Tags: java, junit, h2, in-memory-database

i want to start from my JUnit test an in memory db and fill it with data.
When i start the server via the h2.bat everything works fine for my JUnit test app.

But when i try to start the server form Java i get some sort of connection problems
(when i try to connect to the db by the webinterface i get the gui, but its functionallity is missing/wrong)

code to start the server in the @BeforeClass setup:

```
args = new String[] { "-tcpPort", "8082","-tcpAllowOthers"};
h2Server = Server.createTcpServer(args).start();
// i also tried the createWebServer but it didn't make any difference
```

code to open connection once:

```
String url = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8082/mem:db1";
h2Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"SA","");
```

For some reason i either have no connection to the db but more likely there is some sort of connection but, like said i get some undefiend connection problems.

How could i try to achieve the same functionality as when running the h2.bat from cmdline?
Do i use wrong parameters on createserver?

Update 1:
I found the problem. It seems that the usage of dbUnit to inject my testdata closed my h2connection unexpectetly (still wondering why this did not happen when running the h2.bat cmdline).

I will try now to run the full in memory mode, if it works i will delete this question or write down the problems and solutions for other users.

Update 2:
It works now in full memory mode, i am not sure but for me the core problem seemed to be (which i did not expect) calling:

```
IDatabaseConnection dBUnitConnection = new DatabaseConnection(h2Connection);
....
dbUnitConnection.close()
```

also closed my h2connection.

Like said, this did not happen when i run the h2server from cmdline.

Comment: What do you mean with "its functionallity is missing/wrong" and "there is some sort of connection but, like said i get some undefiend connection problems"? Do you have an exception message and stack trace, or what is wrong?

Comment: When i click on the GUI buttons, my browser downloads me some .jsp files instead of clicking the button. I got a connection lost stacktrace once but i need to try to reproduce it, before i tried the "tcp localhost" i tried (which is the goal) in memory mode "jdbc:h2:mem:db1". I will update the question asap.